# complexity of simple k arrays merge

Tags: arrays, algorithm, merge, time-complexity

In this problem we have n elements in k sorted arrays, and we want to merge them into 1 sorted array of size n.

The optimal solution for the problem is using a min-heap in O(nlogk) time.
but say we want to use only the merge algorithm and merge them all in pairs until we get the output array, what would be the time complexity for that? 
Does it matter if the arrays are all the same size or different sizes?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

`Does it matter if the arrays are all the same size or different sizes?`

No, it doesn't.

At every stage you perform O(N) operations (about 3/2*N, including N/2 comparisons and N movings - every element participates in comparison, and is copied).  And there are Log(K) such stages. Overall complexity O(N*Log(K))

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the size does matter, please tell me if i'm wrong. In case the arrays are at sizes 1,2,4,8,16... (a tree in which every level is a sorted array, k=logn) it can be done in O(n) time:
-merge the smallest array (root) with the next larger array (1+2)
-merge the result with the next larger array (1+2+4) and so on ...

At the final merge we will have 1+2+4+8+...+n/2 comparisons.
Notice that the number of times we compare each element is equal to its height in the tree.(assuming that we count heights from leaves=1) For example, the root will be compared logn times but the leaves will be compared only once, We got that it can be done in O(n):

[Time Complexity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RLNK.jpg)